# How to update from Windows Library Javascript 1.0 to Windows Library Javascript 2.0?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Exp edition for Windows 8, to develop Xbox apps using HTML5 and Javascript. I realized that most of the libraries to handle Voice, Game controller events, etc. are not available in JS library 1.0. How can I update my JS 1.0 library to JS 2.0 library?